# How messenger.com handles authentication

Tags: authentication, architecture

Does anyone know how messenger.com knows which account is logged in on facebook.com and can log you in as that person?

What kind of protocols are being used, libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit more of research I found out that they use a hidden iframe to special url on the facebook.com domain and a post message back with a means of auth for messenger.com app.

That concludes the subject.